How to force system to stop reconnecting devices via USB
I have a problem because from time to time my Dell Precision 3581 laptop restarts the connection with my monitor (Philips Brilliance 346P). Below are the logs from kern.log, when this happens the logs below appear. It is quite random, and sometimes nothing happens all day, and sometimes it is impossible to work and only a reboot helps. I have also added an information from lsusb, lspci and uname. Is anyone able to point out what might be the problem, or what else to throw in?
Additionally, I'll add that this is the only Ubuntu laptop that has the problem with my monitor, but also no other devices with this laptop have the problem.
Best regards.
Draqun
kern.logs
2024-04-12T10:28:13.261740+02:00 dgiebas-ubu-i4b-pl kernel: [12978.733911] audit: type=1400 audit(1712910493.253:18184): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap.skype.skype" name="/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/ACPI0003:00/power_supply/AC/online" pid=4860 comm="skypeforlinux" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
2024-04-12T10:28:13.425739+02:00 dgiebas-ubu-i4b-pl kernel: [12978.897013] usb 4-1: reset SuperSpeed Plus Gen 2x1 USB device number 8 using xhci_hcd
2024-04-12T10:28:13.665741+02:00 dgiebas-ubu-i4b-pl kernel: [12979.136711] usb 4-1.1: USB disconnect, device number 11
2024-04-12T10:28:13.792295+02:00 dgiebas-ubu-i4b-pl kernel: [12979.264988] usb 4-1: reset SuperSpeed Plus Gen 2x1 USB device number 8 using xhci_hcd
2024-04-12T10:28:14.117793+02:00 dgiebas-ubu-i4b-pl kernel: [12979.588826] usb 4-1.1: new SuperSpeed Plus Gen 2x1 USB device number 12 using xhci_hcd
2024-04-12T10:28:14.137730+02:00 dgiebas-ubu-i4b-pl kernel: [12979.611464] usb 4-1.1: New USB device found, idVendor=0bda, idProduct=0420, bcdDevice= 1.42
2024-04-12T10:28:14.137738+02:00 dgiebas-ubu-i4b-pl kernel: [12979.611493] usb 4-1.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
2024-04-12T10:28:14.137739+02:00 dgiebas-ubu-i4b-pl kernel: [12979.611497] usb 4-1.1: Product: 4-Port USB 3.0 Hub
2024-04-12T10:28:14.137739+02:00 dgiebas-ubu-i4b-pl kernel: [12979.611498] usb 4-1.1: Manufacturer: Generic
2024-04-12T10:28:14.141725+02:00 dgiebas-ubu-i4b-pl kernel: [12979.612982] hub 4-1.1:1.0: USB hub found
2024-04-12T10:28:14.141728+02:00 dgiebas-ubu-i4b-pl kernel: [12979.613223] hub 4-1.1:1.0: 4 ports detected
2024-04-12T10:28:14.259404+02:00 dgiebas-ubu-i4b-pl kernel: [12979.733988] audit: type=1400 audit(1712910494.253:18185): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap.skype.skype" name="/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/ACPI0003:00/power_supply/AC/online" pid=4860 comm="skypeforlinux" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0

~> lsusb
damian@dgiebas-ubu-i4b-pl ~> lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0a5c:5842 Broadcom Corp. 58200
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 1bcf:28d2 Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. Integrated_Webcam_FHD
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 8087:0033 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 018: ID 04f2:b612 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd USB2.0 FHD UVC WebCam
Bus 001 Device 017: ID 0bda:4837 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. USB Audio
Bus 001 Device 016: ID 1532:006e Razer USA, Ltd DeathAdder Essential
Bus 001 Device 015: ID 1532:025e Razer USA, Ltd Razer Cynosa V2
Bus 001 Device 012: ID 0bda:5420 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 4-Port USB 2.0 Hub
Bus 001 Device 011: ID 0bda:5420 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 4-Port USB 2.0 Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 014: ID 0bda:0420 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 4-Port USB 3.0 Hub
Bus 004 Device 008: ID 0bda:0420 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 4-Port USB 3.0 Hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

~> lspci
damian@dgiebas-ubu-i4b-pl ~> lspci
0000:00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device a706
0000:00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device a70d
0000:00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Raptor Lake-P [Iris Xe Graphics] (rev 04)
0000:00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device a71d
0000:00:06.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation RST VMD Managed Controller
0000:00:07.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device a76e
0000:00:07.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device a73f
0000:00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Device a74f
0000:00:0d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Device a71e
0000:00:0d.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation Device a73e
0000:00:0e.0 RAID bus controller: Intel Corporation Volume Management Device NVMe RAID Controller Intel Corporation
0000:00:12.0 Serial controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake-P Integrated Sensor Hub (rev 01)
0000:00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH USB 3.2 xHCI Host Controller (rev 01)
0000:00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH Shared SRAM (rev 01)
0000:00:14.3 Network controller: Intel Corporation Device 51f1 (rev 01)
0000:00:15.0 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 01)
0000:00:15.1 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH Serial IO I2C Controller #1 (rev 01)
0000:00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH HECI Controller (rev 01)
0000:00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCI Express x1 Root Port #10 (rev 01)
0000:00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device 519d (rev 01)
0000:00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Device 51ca (rev 01)
0000:00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH-P SMBus Host Controller (rev 01)
0000:00:1f.5 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake-P PCH SPI Controller (rev 01)
0000:00:1f.6 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Device 0dc5 (rev 01)
0000:01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 25bd (rev a1)
0000:72:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS525A PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
10000:e0:06.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device a74d
10000:e0:06.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device a73d
10000:e1:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Shenzhen Longsys Electronics Co., Ltd. Device 1602 (rev 01)
10000:e2:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: SK hynix Device 1d59 (rev 03)
damian@dgiebas-ubu-i4b-pl ~> 

~> uname -a
damian@dgiebas-ubu-i4b-pl ~> uname -a
Linux dgiebas-ubu-i4b-pl 6.2.0-39-generic #40-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Tue Nov 14 14:18:00 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

EDIT:
After installation > sudo apt install nvidia-driver-550
2024-06-13T11:12:24.991734+02:00 dgiebas-ubu-i4b-pl kernel: usb 2-1: reset SuperSpeed Plus Gen 2x1 USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
2024-06-13T11:12:25.214658+02:00 dgiebas-ubu-i4b-pl kernel: usb 2-1.1: USB disconnect, device number 7
2024-06-13T11:12:25.329709+02:00 dgiebas-ubu-i4b-pl kernel: usb 2-1: reset SuperSpeed Plus Gen 2x1 USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
2024-06-13T11:12:25.623661+02:00 dgiebas-ubu-i4b-pl kernel: usb 2-1.1: new SuperSpeed Plus Gen 2x1 USB device number 8 using xhci_hcd
2024-06-13T11:12:25.638645+02:00 dgiebas-ubu-i4b-pl kernel: usb 2-1.1: New USB device found, idVendor=0bda, idProduct=0420, bcdDevice= 1.42
2024-06-13T11:12:25.638650+02:00 dgiebas-ubu-i4b-pl kernel: usb 2-1.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
2024-06-13T11:12:25.638651+02:00 dgiebas-ubu-i4b-pl kernel: usb 2-1.1: Product: 4-Port USB 3.0 Hub
2024-06-13T11:12:25.638651+02:00 dgiebas-ubu-i4b-pl kernel: usb 2-1.1: Manufacturer: Generic
2024-06-13T11:12:25.639678+02:00 dgiebas-ubu-i4b-pl kernel: hub 2-1.1:1.0: USB hub found
2024-06-13T11:12:25.639680+02:00 dgiebas-ubu-i4b-pl kernel: hub 2-1.1:1.0: 4 ports detected


lspci gives you
0000:01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 25bd (rev a1)
which means you have a nvidia graphics card, run sudo update-pciids then lspci to check
the dell documentation at page 29 suggests you may have a RTX A500, A1000 or A2000
you probably have not installed the nvidia proprietary drivers, run sudo apt install nvidia-driver-550 for the latest driver which is compatible with the above graphics cards
there are also open source drivers but they may be more of a hassle
let us know if it fixes the problem

Hi. Thank you for your answer. I'v installed driver, but there still is problem. I've updated main post with new log. Any other ideas?

is the disconnecting correlated with the battery level ? this laptop needs a 130W charger but your monitor can only provide 90W

I doubt it, but I'll plug in the charger and keep an eye on it. A laptop connected to a monitor always has 100% battery life even after a whole day of work.

dell has a proprietary charging protocol, the PC probably probes the non dell charger every now and then, which might restart the connection
additionally, the laptop might throttle on 90W which might also cause this issue
